# What's the difference between a form of a language and a dialect of a language?

Tags: terminology, dialects, varieties

I was wondering what's the difference between a **form** of a language and a **dialect** of a language?

For example, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_American_and_British_English) states that **British English** is a form of English and not a dialect of English.

[Another page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_English) states that "Standard Singapore English" is not a dialect, but a form of English. It also states that "Singapore Colloquial English" is a form of English.

What's the difference between a form of a language and a dialect of a language?

Comment: The technical terms used within linguistics rather than ***form*** are [***variety*** and ***lect***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_\(linguistics\))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answering this question requires defining "language" and "dialect". It's easier to do this by using the non-technical word "variety".

> **Language**: speech varieties are different languages if they are not mutually intelligible.
>
> **Dialect**: speech varieties are dialects of a language if they are mutually intelligible but differ in systematic ways.

Some examples of dialects of English
Britain: Received Pronunciation (or RP), Yorkshire English, Estuary English, Scouse, Norfolk English, etc. Through various historical accidents RP came to be the most prestigious dialect.
The USA: General American, North-Central, Midland, Greater New York City, etc. General American is the variety with the fewest obvious regional features, and is used especially in the media. [Rick Aschmann](http://aschmann.net/AmEng/) has an excellent and detailed introduction to North American English dialectology.

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_American_and_British_English) that says: "British English is the form of English used in the United Kingdom. It includes all English dialects used within the United Kingdom." is simply using the non-technical term "form" to refer to the grouping of all dialects of English found in the United Kingdom.

As for the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_English) on Singapore English, I can't see where it says that "'Standard Singapore English' is not a dialect, but a form of English". It does say that Singapore Standard English is very similar to standard British English (which I assume refers to RP). Singapore Colloquial English (aka [Singlish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singlish)) on the other hand, while based largely on English (as well as on the other languages of Singapore) is so different from English that it is not usually considered a dialect of English (ie it is not mutually intelligible with any other dialect of English) but a creole.

So in short, referring to a "form" of a language is a non-technical usage that could cover any variety, or grouping of varieties, of a language (ie dialects, idiolects, registers, genres, jargons, etc).  But the term "dialect" is a technical term within linguistics.

Comment: Btw regarding your definition of *language* and *dialect*.. Since "Hokkien" and "Chinese" are not mutually intelligible, are you saying that "Hokkien" is considered a *language* and not considered a *dialect* of Chinese?

Comment: @Pacerier I'm not sure what you mean by "Chinese", perhaps Mandarin? If so, yes, Hokkien and Mandarin are not mutually intelligible and so are different "languages", in the technical, linguistic sense of the word.

Comment: Ok, just to confirm, you are saying that "British English" is a **group of dialects**, and it is **not a dialect**, for the same reason *a group of animals* is not an *animal* right?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, there is no UK English dialect called "British English", the term refers collectively to all of the dialects of English found in Britain.

Comment: Ic, so blunders http://bit.ly/KD51Xz  is wrong then.

Comment: No, it isn't wrong. It is using "dialect" in a less finely-grained sense than you are in this question. Your assumption that a particular set of criteria distinguishes the meanings of a set of words _for all contexts in which they might be used_ is what is wrong.

Comment: @ColinFine What do you mean by "less finely-grained"? Re your second comment, perhaps I misunderstand you, but technical terminology has to retain a core meaning across all usages or else it is of no use.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut: I don't agree. Some technical words do have one or more precise meanings, but many technical terms, particularly in a "soft" science like linguistics, are subject to endless discussion about their precise meaning, with a result that different writers end up using them in slightly different ways. This is a problem when somebody asks a general question like this, but for most purposes it's enough that the meaning is clear enough in the context in which it is used. So for some purposes it can be useful to describe "British English" as a dialect, and for other purposes not.

Comment: @ColinFine While it's reasonable in a non-technical context to talk about people as speaking "British English", in fact there is no speech community (or individual) that speaks "British English". The speech communities in Britain have many dialects which, taken together, can be referred to as "British English", but they each have their own dialect. If I wanted to find a speaker of "British English" where would I go? And if I got any two speakers of "British English" together, would they agree that they speak the same way?

Comment: @ColinFine I should add, my view is that the definition of "dialect" in linguistics is reasonably settled and precise; I'm not aware of there being "endless discussion about their precise meaning". The fuzziness (and there is plenty) comes from the difficulties in applying the definition to particular circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

### Types of Language Forms:

- **Idiolect:** language form of the single speaker.
- **Standard Dialect:** group dialect that is supported by institutions.
- **Non-Standard Dialect:** dialect that is not supported by institutions, and is non-singular. One type of non-standard dialect is a **sociolect**, which is a dialect associated with a social group such as a socioeconomic class, an ethnic group, an age group, etc.

Though I might be wrong, my guess is that in the examples you provided, the author intended to mean that a dialect was standard or non-standard, and confused a language form as being a standard dialect.

Comment: Do you mean to say that *British English* is a *standard dialect* of English?

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes, I do, since British English is the dialect of English used by the Government of the United Kingdom, which would mean British English is a standard dialect of English.

Comment: Btw just to confirm, you are saying that American English is also a standard dialect of English, and we have many dialects of British English, and we also have many dialects of American English?

Comment: I think at this point we might have to clarify that **standard** does not imply **standardized** with regard to British English, American English, etc.

Comment: Yes, American English is the standard dialect of the Federal government of the United States. The key I believe to your last question is 'dialects of', which is to say none of those dialects would be as [hippietrail says](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1915/whats-the-difference-between-a-form-of-a-language-and-a-dialect-of-a-language/1916#comment5018_1916) **standardized** form of the language, but the sum of those dialects form a **standard** dialect; meaning American English is not British English, or vice versa.

Comment: @blunders Ok, Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_English) states that American English is a set of dialects of the English language. Does it mean that "a set of dialects" can also be called (is equivalent to) "a dialect"?

Comment: It should also be pointed out that within British English there is another "standard" variety which would be _Received Pronunciation_.

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes, a '[subdialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdialect)' is a subdivision of dialect. Subdialects can be divided further, ultimately down to idiolects.

Comment: +1 @Danger Fourpence: Agree, was going to point that out [Received Pronunciation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation), but thought it might confuse the matter further.

Comment: @blunders Ok, as shown in http://goo.gl/CwmBM, what I was trying to say is that Shouldn't "American English" and "British English" be considered "groups of dialects" and not a "dialect"? In other words they are "groups" and not themselves considered "dialects" right?

Comment: @Pacerier: Any dialects is able to have subdialects, and I'm unaware of a name for a 'root dialect' other than 'Standard Dialect'; a 'root dialect' being a dialect that was not a subdialect of another dialect.

Comment: @blunders Hmm, maybe "British English" and "American English" aren't dialects at all, but collective names of dialects.

Comment: @Pacerier: No, they are standard dialects.

Comment: @blunders Gaston seems to disagree with you: http://goo.gl/4jIf5

Comment: @Pacerier: [bit.ly/BritishEnglish](http://bit.ly/BritishEnglish)

Comment: @blunders Ok this is confusing =X So you are saying that Gaston is wrong?

Comment: @Pacerier: I'm saying figure it out for yourself.